# Images not displaying in Slider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, contentful, react-props

I am working on a GatsbyJS project, using Contentful, and have created a template 'BlogPost'. Inside this template, I have imported a 'ResearchSlider' component. However, the images are not displaying at all.

I have passed down the image url data, as props, down to the researchSlider, which is then put inside the component state, and used in a function that passes each piece of image data into the 'Slide' child component, using a for loop. In 'Slide', the piece of image data is used as the value for backgroundImage in the styles of a div.

I would like to understand why they are not displaying and how I can fix this.

Here is the relevant code.

ResearchSlider component:

```
export default class ResearchSlider extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
                images: [this.props.firstSlide, 
                    this.props.secondSlide, 
                    this.props.thirdSlide
                    ], 
                translateValue: 0, 
                index: 0
    }

    this.renderSlides = this.renderSlides.bind(this);
    this.handleClickPrevious = this.handleClickPrevious.bind(this);
    this.handleClickNext = this.handleClickNext.bind(this);
    this.slideWidth = this.slideWidth.bind(this);
}

renderSlides() {
    const images = this.state.images;
    let slides = []

    for(let i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
      slides.push(<Slide key={i} image={images[i]} />)

    return slides
}

render() {
    const { translateValue } = this.state
    return(
        <div className='slider'>
            <div className="slider-wrapper"
                style={{
                    transform: `translateX(${translateValue}px)`,
                    transition: 'transform ease-out 0.3s'
                }}>
                { this.renderSlides() }
            </div>

            <ClickPrevious slideRight={this.handleClickPrevious}/>
            <ClickNext slideLeft={this.handleClickNext}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

'Slide' component:

import React from 'react';

```
const Slide = ({image}) => {
    const styles = {
        backgroundImage: `url("${image}")`,
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
        backgroundPosition: '50% 60%'
      }

      return <div className="slide" style={styles}></div>
    }

export default Slide
```

Here is a screenshot of the inspection:

[image]

Comment: What's the final background url when you inspect the element? is `this.props.secondSlide` a string ?

Comment: Hay Khaled, thank you for your reply! Yes, it appears to be a string. I've added a screenshot to my post.

Comment: Ah ok your problem is simpler i think, did you try to attach the protocol. ‘https:’ to the asset link?

Comment: oh! thank you so much, it works now :D. And thank you for your excellent videos on Contentful and gatsbyJS on youtube!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I will make answer for future users with the same issues, it would be nice if you can mark it as a correct answer.
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

contentful assets URLs don't have the protocol attached to them they will in the following format `//images.contentful.com/......` when setting this url to the `src` of an `<img>` tag the browser will assign the protocol automatically based on the protocol you app is using. But using the url in css you need to append explicitly the protocol to the url.
You Slide component should look like this.

```
const Slide = ({image}) => {
    const styles = {
        backgroundImage: `url("https:${image}")`,
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
        backgroundPosition: '50% 60%'
      }

      return <div className="slide" style={styles}></div>
    }

export default Slide
```